# ggplot histogram colour by group not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Ok I have a df like this

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6,7)
ab <- data.frame(a, b)
ab
```

I plot a simple histogram with ggplot and try colour by x variable.

```
ggplot(ab, aes(x=a, fill=a)) +geom_histogram()
```

The output plot does not colour. Im clearly making a small error somewhere.

[image: Output graph looks like this]

Comment: In your histogram, there should be one color only! shouldn't it?

Comment: Try `ggplot(ab, aes(x=a, fill=as.factor(a))) +geom_histogram()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it, `a` need to be factor

```
    library(ggplot2)
    a <- c(1,2,2,3)
    b <- c(4,5,6,7)
    ab <- data.frame(a, b)
    ab 
    
    ggplot(ab, aes(x=a, fill=as.factor(a))) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work better with a bar geometry.  For the fill to work, you can change `a` into a factor.

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6,7)
ab <- data.frame(a, b)
ab 

ggplot(ab, aes(x=a, 
               fill=as.factor(a))) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]